# How to execute an action if another action doesn't complete within 10 seconds?

Tags: swift

I have the following piece of code I want to execute at app startup:

```
let database = "https://example.com" // A website.
let databaseURL = URL(string: "\(database)")!
        var databaseRequest = URLRequest(url: databaseURL)
        databaseRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(databaseRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) {(response, data, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let databaseContents = data
            let databaseFile = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("local.txt")
            do {
                try databaseContents.write(to: databaseFile)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

I want to give this code 10 seconds to run. If it takes longer than 10 seconds, abort it and do something else, like this:

```
print("ERROR: Could not retrieve list.")
let warningToUser = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "We couldn't retrieve your preferences, so they have been reset to default values. We will try again next time you launch this app.", preferredStyle: .alert)
warningToUser.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
self.present(warningToUser, animated: true)
```

I don't even what to try. Any help is highly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Unreleated, but why use `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest` and not `URLSession`?  Else, what about using `timeoutInterval` property of the `URLRequest` to 10 seconds? It's available in the init method or you can set it later...

Comment: `let databaseRequest = URLRequest(url: databaseURL, timeoutInterval: 10.0)` Does that work? How can I then do an action if `databaseURL` isn't reachable within those 10 seconds?

Comment: Did you read the documentation of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/1418229-timeoutinterval ?  Also, did you try a invalid URL just to test, and/or cutting the Internet connection? And see either `data` closure parameter and `error` parameter and/or response `parameter` too?

Comment: I tried replacing the URL with `vhdbvjhebvhrebv.com` (something totally random) and still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set **timeoutInterval** and check the error after timeoutInterval.

```
    let database = "https://example.com" // A website.
    let databaseURL = URL(string: "\(database)")!
    var databaseRequest = URLRequest(url: databaseURL, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
    databaseRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(databaseRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main) {(response, data, error) in
        if error != nil {
              print("ERROR: Could not retrieve list.")
              let warningToUser = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "We couldn't retrieve your preferences, so they have been reset to default values. We will try again next tine you launch this app.", preferredStyle: .alert)
              warningToUser.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
              self.present(warningToUser, animated: true)
        }else {
              guard let data = data else { return }
              let databaseContents = data
              let databaseFile = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("local.txt")
              do {
                    try databaseContents.write(to: databaseFile)
              } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
              }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the time interval of the URLrequest.
Just put this line in your code `databaseRequest.timeoutInterval = 10`

Comment: Did that, nothing happened, probably because nothing was meant to happen. How can I print an error message after those 10 seconds have passed?

Comment: maybe you can use Timer instead.